# Limit of continuous function: behavior near point 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function satisfying $\displaystyle \lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{f(s)}{s}=0$.

Define $f^* : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ by $f^*(s):=\max\{f(x): {0\le x\le s}\}$ for $s \in [0,\infty)$.

I'd like to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{s\to 0^+}\frac{f^*(s)}{s}=0$. 
It seems true, but I cannot prove it.

Please let me know if you have any comments. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $f$ is continuous we have  by the Extreme Value Theorem that the maximum of $f$ on the interval $[0,s]$ is attained at some point, let's says $x_0 \in [0,s]$. So $f^*(s) = \max\{f(x): {0\le x\le s}\} = f(x_0)$

From the limit you have that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta >0$ .s.t. $0 < s < \delta \implies \frac{f(s)}{s} < \epsilon$

Now let $\epsilon > 0$ be given then we have that:

$$0 < s < \delta \implies \frac{f^*(s)}{s} = \frac{\max\{f(x): {0\le x\le s}\}}{s} = \frac{f(x_0)}{s} \le \frac{f(x_0)}{x_0} < \epsilon$$

The last inequality follows as $0 < x_0 \le s < \delta$